# Lightweight .NET design architecture to render a graph

Tags: .net

I'm currently working on a project that would be plotting a graph against data from DB using Raphael. I would have a drop-down that acts a filter for the graph. Based on the drop-down selection, the graph would be populated.

Can anyone suggest a .NET architecture (ASP.NET webform /MVC site/anything else that'd suit this) for this requirement? It's pretty simple. The graph has to be generated based on the drop-down and there is no other change in the page involved.

I need the design to be light-weight, fast and simple and it has to be based on .NET.

Thanks.